# Undefined error when submitting email form using Pear

Tags: php, forms, email, smtp

I am trying to get an email form working but it keeps erroring out.

My contact.php code looks like this:

```
<?php

ini_set("include_path", '/home4/hipsiguy/php:' . ini_get("include_path") );

require_once "Mail.php";

$username = 'my@emailaddress.ca';
$password = 'myemailpassword';
$smtpHost = 'mail.myemailserver.ca';
$smtpPort = '465';
$to = 'my@emailaddress.ca';
$from = 'my@emailaddress.ca';

$subject = 'Contact Form';
$successMessage = 'Message successfully sent!';

$replyTo = $_POST['your-email'];
$name = $_POST['your-name'];
$body = $_POST['your-message'];

$headers = array(
    'From' => $name . " <" . $from . ">",
    'Reply-To' => $name . " <" . $replyTo . ">",
    'To' => $to,
    'Subject' => $subject
);
$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp', array(
            'host' => $smtpHost,
            'port' => $smtpPort,
            'auth' => true,
            'username' => $username,
            'password' => $password
        ));

$mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);

if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
    echo($mail->getMessage());
} else {
    echo($successMessage);
}
?>
```

I host with HostGator (if that matters) and have installed the Mail and Net_SMTP extensions through CPanel.

I have tried a couple different methods, all of which error out.

The errors below seem to be the most common.

> [16-Sep-2021 08:27:00 America/Chicago] PHP Warning:  require_once(Mail.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home4/hipsiguy/public_html/TEST/contact.php on line 30

> [16-Sep-2021 08:27:00 America/Chicago] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'Mail.php' (include_path='.:/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/share/pear:/usr/lib/pear') in /home4/hipsiguy/public_html/TEST/contact.php on line 30

What am I missing?

Comment: Should it me `mail.php` rather than `Mail.php` Linux being case sensitive?

Comment: Pear Mail is pretty ancient, you'll be better off using something more modern like SwiftMailer or PHPMailer.

Comment: mail.php has also errored out with the same error code.

Comment: So where is `Mail.php` (or `mail.php`, please specify which one it actually is) located in your file system?

Comment: /home4/hipsiguy/php/Mail.php.  &   

/home4/hipsiguy/php/Mail/mail.php

Im not even sure which one it is. But I've tried both paths without success.